# How to create a new directory by copying a directory from same repo while keeping history in Git

Tags: git, github

I have directories inside a repository and i need to copy one directory and put it in same repo keeping history intact

```
repo  
  /dir1  
  /dir2  
  /dir3
```

after change i need it like

```
repo  
  /dir1  
  /dir2  
  /dir3  
  /dir4  (copy of dir 3 with all history of directory 3)
```

Purpose of doing this is that same code is being used by a different team  so want to segregate  it

I have tried below commands

```
step1: cloning the repo 
step2: cd repo   
step3: git status  
step4: git remote rm origin  
step5: git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir3 -- --all  
step6: mkdir dir4  
step7: mv * dir4  
step8: git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:test.git  
step9: git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

on step9 i am getting merge conflict in `readme.md` an `.gitignore` file

Comment: Hi Rohit. SO is a Q&A site. But this is not a question.

Comment: Hi Romain, my question is how to achieve the above scenario i mentioned , along with that i have also posted what i tried so far

Comment: Then I think you should edit the question or its title to make it clearer.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the merge conflicts?

Comment: D Malan, yes i tried that but it didnt work